# How to convert .xls to .csv in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, export-to-csv, import-from-excel, ssconvert

I have a text file (abc.txt) which will be having the file name along with the path which is to be converted to .csv. Below is the script I wrote:

```
 {while IFS= read -r f ; do
 filename="${f%.*}"
 ssconvert ${filename}.xls ${filename}.csv
done < abc.txt}
```

Problem is the file .xls file name having space in it. So the script is not working,says:

> Unable to guess exporter to use for 'file:

Comment: the question is terse in that you've not given details on how the filenames are arranged in the text file abc.txt. To be specific, what is the record separator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should surround the following in double-quotes to prevent globbing and word splitting:

```
ssconvert "${filename}.xls" "${filename}.csv"
```

Also include a space between your curly-brackets and the next/previous object `{ ... }`:

```
{ while IFS= read -r f ; do
      filename="${f%.*}"
      ssconvert "${filename}.xls" "${filename}.csv"
done < abc.txt ; }
```

Note: If you are still having issues with the "export type" error mentioned in the comments maybe try `ssconvert "${filename}".xls "${filename}".csv` as I'm not familiar with the exact syntax it requires. You can check your scripts easily with the online tool [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net).

Comment: @I'L'I, i am getting An output file name or an explicit export type is required error.

Comment: @Midhun, Check the updated example and let me know if that works. You can also try it like `"${filename}".xls`...

Comment: You might have guessed what is the problem with `"${filename}.xls ${filename}.csv"` ie  `ssconvert` would consider the entire stuff as one argument.  The change should work though. :)

Comment: @sjsam, Yeah I'm not familiar with how ssconvert deals with the output types, so I assumed that might've been the issue - thx!

Comment: BTW, the error imho has nothing to do with `ssconvert`, it is just that the second argument was missing with the previous version of this answer. Note that [\[ comment#1 \]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42778112/how-to-convert-xls-to-cvs-in-unix#comment72670983_42778160) says `An output file name... is required`

Comment: @sjsam: Yep definitely... I've been away for a bit, so literally "spaced it".

Comment: @Midhun : You may accept the answer if it worked. That is the official way of saying Thank you here :)

Comment: Is there a way to convert xlsx with multiple tabs to csv. Least case i want to convert 1st tab.

Comment: @Midhun: Ask a new question regarding that.